# How to pass the variables from one javascript to another javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
// getting college data
const clglogin = document.querySelector('#college-login-form');
clglogin.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
// get user info
const clg_email = clglogin['college-login-email'].value;
const clg_password = clglogin['college-login-pwd'].value;
localStorage.setItem("email_clg",clg_email);
//login the user
const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(clg_email, clg_password)
.then(function(firebaseUser) {
window.location="college_profile.html";
.catch(function(error) {
window.alert("Email ID or Password Incorrect");
});
});
```

How can I pass the values of the **clg_email** to other js without using the **localStorage.setItem**

Comment: Within the same document you can use a global variable.

Comment: I have two html files school.html and college.html as well as school.js and college.js. The login page is in index.html. I need to get the value from login.js and pass to school.js or college.js to  load the respective html pages

Comment: You should handle the login credentials and other login logic at your server. Don't pass the credentials allover your client-side pages.